# fseminf with 1 dimensional constraint

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to use fseminf function in matlab optimization enviroment:

```
clc;
clear;
close;

% Define function 
global g f S
f= @(x) -x(1);
g= @(x,s) x(1)-x(2).*s(1)-x(3).*(-sqrt((2.25-10.*sqrt(12).*...
(s(1)-1.175).^2)./(5.*sqrt(24)))+1.2);
lb=[-Inf,0,0];
ub=[Inf,1,1];
S=[0.9220144,1.42985]; 
x0= [0.5,0.5,0.5]'; % initial condition
A= [];
b=[];
Aeq= [0,1,1];
beq= [1];
[x,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = fseminf(f,x0,1,@seminfcon2,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub);
```

---

**seminfcon2 is defined as follows:**

```
function [c, ceq, K1, s] = seminfcon2(x,s)
global S g

% No finite nonlinear inequality and equality constraints
c = [];
ceq = [];

% Sample set
if isnan(s(1,1))
      s(1,1)=0.001;
      s(1,2)=0;
end
t = S(1):s(1):S(2);
K1 = g(x,t);
```

Here are the details, the thing is it does not work properly, I get the solution which does not satisfy the contraints. It states:

> Local minimum found that satisfies the constraints.↵↵Optimization
>   completed because the objective function is non-decreasing in
>   ↵feasible directions, to within the value of the optimality tolerance.

I know that the constraints are not satisfied because

1. I drew the constraint area
2. my other alghoritms do produce a good result

My question is to people who know how `fseminf` function works. Is it possible that this alghoritm can not perform an optimization for my example? To add, `fseminf` works fine with my other examples.

---

**EDIT**

- The solution found by the algorithm is:`(1.1633,       0,     1.0000)`
- whereas my other algorithms produced:   `(0.99069,  0.55395, 0.44605)`

Comment: Could you post the given solution not satisfying the constraints?

Comment: @Adam Its updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few mistakes:**

- `f` is a function of `x` ***and*** `s`, not only `x`

```
f = @(x, s) -x(1);
```

- ***Semi-infinite constraint*** is evaluated on the ***entire interval***, not at
  a fixed point
- Replace `s(1)` in `g(x, s)` by `s` ***without indexing***, the whole
  interval will be used
- **Semi-infinite constraint** `g(x, s)` is as follows

```
g = @(x,s) x(1)-x(2).*s-x(3).*(-sqrt((2.25-10.*sqrt(12).*...
(s-1.175).^2)./(5.*sqrt(24)))+1.2);
```

**solution**

```
x = [0.9907    0.5546    0.4454]
```

Comment: Wow, I can not believe it, it was s(1) because I performed multidimensional optimization, where you use coordinates s(1), s(2) etc.  It was enough to change s(1) to s and it produced a good result, thank you! To be precise I do not think f is a function of x and s.

Comment: Including `s` is just to comply with `fseminf` syntax, but yes you can ignore it as well. Check this link https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/one-dimensional-semi-infinite-constraints.html